# How to create a generator/iterator with the Python C API?

Tags: python, c, iterator, generator, python-c-api

How do I replicate the following Python code with the Python C API?

```
class Sequence():
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    def data(self):
        i = 0
        while i < self.max:
            yield i
            i += 1
```

So far, I have this:

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
#include <Python/structmember.h>

/* Define a new object class, Sequence. */
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    size_t max;
} SequenceObject;

/* Instance variables */
static PyMemberDef Sequence_members[] = {
    {"max", T_UINT, offsetof(SequenceObject, max), 0, NULL},
    {NULL} /* Sentinel */
};

static int Sequence_Init(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "k", &(self->max))) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static PyObject *Sequence_data(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args);

/* Methods */
static PyMethodDef Sequence_methods[] = {
    {"data", (PyCFunction)Sequence_data, METH_NOARGS,
     "sequence.data() -> iterator object\n"
     "Returns iterator of range [0, sequence.max)."},
    {NULL} /* Sentinel */
};

/* Define new object type */
PyTypeObject Sequence_Type = {
   PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
   0,                         /* ob_size */
   "Sequence",                /* tp_name */
   sizeof(SequenceObject),    /* tp_basicsize */
   0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
   0,                         /* tp_dealloc */
   0,                         /* tp_print */
   0,                         /* tp_getattr */
   0,                         /* tp_setattr */
   0,                         /* tp_compare */
   0,                         /* tp_repr */
   0,                         /* tp_as_number */
   0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
   0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
   0,                         /* tp_hash */
   0,                         /* tp_call */
   0,                         /* tp_str */
   0,                         /* tp_getattro */
   0,                         /* tp_setattro */
   0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
   Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags*/
   "Test generator object",   /* tp_doc */
   0,                         /* tp_traverse */
   0,                         /* tp_clear */
   0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
   0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
   0,                         /* tp_iter */
   0,                         /* tp_iternext */
   0,                         /* tp_methods */
   Sequence_members,          /* tp_members */
   0,                         /* tp_getset */
   0,                         /* tp_base */
   0,                         /* tp_dict */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
   0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
   (initproc)Sequence_init,   /* tp_init */
   0,                         /* tp_alloc */
   PyType_GenericNew,         /* tp_new */
};

static PyObject *Sequence_data(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    /* Now what? */
}
```

But I'm not sure where to go next. Could anyone offer some suggestions?

## Edit

I suppose the main problem I'm having with this is simulating the `yield` statement. As I understand it, it is a pretty simple-looking, but in reality complex, statement — it creates a generator with its own `__iter__()` and `next()` methods which are called automatically. Searching through the docs, it seems to be associated with the [PyGenObject](http://docs.python.org/c-api/gen.html); however, how to create a new instance of this object is unclear. `PyGen_New()` takes as its argument a `PyFrameObject`, the only reference to which I can find is [`PyEval_GetFrame()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/reflection.html), which doesn't seem to be what I want (or am I mistaken?). Does anyone have any experience with this they can share?

## Further Edit

I found this to be clearer when I (essentially) expanded what Python was doing behind the scenes:

```
class IterObject():
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    def __iter__(self):
        self.i = 0
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.i >= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.i += 1
        return self.i

class Sequence():
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    def data(self):
        return IterObject(self.max)
```

Technically the sequence is off by one but you get the idea.

The only problem with this is it's very annoying to create a new object every time one needs a generator — even more so in Python than C because of the required monstrosity that comes with defining a new type. And there can be no `yield` statement in C because C has no closures. What I did instead (since I couldn't find it in the Python API — *please* point me to a standard object if it already exists!) was create a simple, generic generator object class that called back a C function for every `next()` method call. Here it is (note that I have not yet tried compiling this because it is not complete — see below):

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
#include <Python/structmember.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* A convenient, generic generator object. */

typedef PyObject *(*callback)(PyObject *callee, void *info) PyGeneratorCallback;

typedef struct {
    PyObject HEAD
    PyGeneratorCallback callback;
    PyObject *callee;
    void *callbackInfo; /* info to be passed along to callback function. */
    bool freeInfo; /* true if |callbackInfo| should be free'()d when object
                    * dealloc's, false if not. */
} GeneratorObject;

static PyObject *Generator_iter(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_INCREF(self);
    return self;
}

static PyObject *Generator_next(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return self->callback(self->callee, self->callbackInfo);
}

static PyMethodDef Generator_methods[] = {
    {"__iter__", (PyCFunction)Generator_iter, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
    {"next", (PyCFunction)Generator_next, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
    {NULL} /* Sentinel */
};

static void Generator_dealloc(GenericEventObject *self)
{
    if (self->freeInfo && self->callbackInfo != NULL) {
        free(self->callbackInfo);
    }
    self->ob_type->tp_free((PyObject *)self);
}

PyTypeObject Generator_Type = {
   PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
   0,                         /* ob_size */
   "Generator",               /* tp_name */
   sizeof(GeneratorObject),   /* tp_basicsize */
   0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
   Generator_dealloc,         /* tp_dealloc */
   0,                         /* tp_print */
   0,                         /* tp_getattr */
   0,                         /* tp_setattr */
   0,                         /* tp_compare */
   0,                         /* tp_repr */
   0,                         /* tp_as_number */
   0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
   0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
   0,                         /* tp_hash */
   0,                         /* tp_call */
   0,                         /* tp_str */
   0,                         /* tp_getattro */
   0,                         /* tp_setattro */
   0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
   Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags*/
   0,                         /* tp_doc */
   0,                         /* tp_traverse */
   0,                         /* tp_clear */
   0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
   0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
   0,                         /* tp_iter */
   0,                         /* tp_iternext */
   0,                         /* tp_methods */
   0,                         /* tp_members */
   0,                         /* tp_getset */
   0,                         /* tp_base */
   0,                         /* tp_dict */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
   0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
   0,                         /* tp_init */
   0,                         /* tp_alloc */
   PyType_GenericNew,         /* tp_new */
};

/* Returns a new generator object with the given callback function
 * and arguments. */
PyObject *Generator_New(PyObject *callee, void *info,
                        bool freeInfo, PyGeneratorCallback callback)
{
    GeneratorObject *generator = (GeneratorObject *)_PyObject_New(&Generator_Type);
    if (generator == NULL) return NULL;

    generator->callee = callee;
    generator->info = info;
    generator->callback = callback;
    self->freeInfo = freeInfo;

    return (PyObject *)generator;
}

/* End of Generator definition. */

/* Define a new object class, Sequence. */
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    size_t max;
} SequenceObject;

/* Instance variables */
static PyMemberDef Sequence_members[] = {
    {"max", T_UINT, offsetof(SequenceObject, max), 0, NULL},
    {NULL} /* Sentinel */
}

static int Sequence_Init(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "k", &self->max)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static PyObject *Sequence_data(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args);

/* Methods */
static PyMethodDef Sequence_methods[] = {
    {"data", (PyCFunction)Sequence_data, METH_NOARGS,
     "sequence.data() -> iterator object\n"
     "Returns generator of range [0, sequence.max)."},
    {NULL} /* Sentinel */
};

/* Define new object type */
PyTypeObject Sequence_Type = {
   PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
   0,                         /* ob_size */
   "Sequence",                /* tp_name */
   sizeof(SequenceObject),    /* tp_basicsize */
   0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
   0,                         /* tp_dealloc */
   0,                         /* tp_print */
   0,                         /* tp_getattr */
   0,                         /* tp_setattr */
   0,                         /* tp_compare */
   0,                         /* tp_repr */
   0,                         /* tp_as_number */
   0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
   0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
   0,                         /* tp_hash */
   0,                         /* tp_call */
   0,                         /* tp_str */
   0,                         /* tp_getattro */
   0,                         /* tp_setattro */
   0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
   Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags*/
   "Test generator object",   /* tp_doc */
   0,                         /* tp_traverse */
   0,                         /* tp_clear */
   0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
   0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
   0,                         /* tp_iter */
   0,                         /* tp_iternext */
   0,                         /* tp_methods */
   Sequence_members,          /* tp_members */
   0,                         /* tp_getset */
   0,                         /* tp_base */
   0,                         /* tp_dict */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
   0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
   (initproc)Sequence_init,   /* tp_init */
   0,                         /* tp_alloc */
   PyType_GenericNew,         /* tp_new */
};

static PyObject *Sequence_data(SequenceObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    size_t *info = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    if (info == NULL) return NULL;
    *info = 0;

    /* |info| will be free'()d by the returned generator object. */
    GeneratorObject *ret = Generator_New(self, info, true,
                                         &Sequence_data_next_callback);
    if (ret == NULL) {
        free(info); /* Watch out for memory leaks! */
    }
    return ret;
}

PyObject *Sequence_data_next_callback(PyObject *self, void *info)
{
    size_t i = info;
    if (i > self->max) {
        return NULL; /* TODO: How do I raise StopIteration here? I can't seem to find
                      *       a standard exception. */
    } else {
        return Py_BuildValue("k", i++);
    }
}
```

However, unfortunately, I'm still not finished. The only question I have left is: How do I raise a `StopIteration` exception with the C API? I can't seem to find it listed in the [Standard Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#standard-exceptions). Also, perhaps more importantly, is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Thanks to anyone that's still following this.

Comment: You are aware that this is `xrange( max )` ?

Comment: Yes, but this is just a simple example. I do have a practical use for this.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Below is a simple implementation of module `spam` with one function `myiter(int)` returning iterator:

```
import spam
for i in spam.myiter(10):
    print i
```

prints numbers from 0 to 9.

It is simpler then your case but shows main points: defining object with standard `__iter__()` and `next()` methods, and implementing iterator behaviour including raising `StopIteration` when appropriate.

In your case iterator object needs to hold reference to Sequence (so you'll need deallocator method for it to Py_DECREF it).
The sequence itself needs to implement `__iter()__` and create an iterator inside it.

---

Structure containing state of iterator.
(In your version instead of m, it would have reference to Sequence.)

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
  long int m;
  long int i;
} spam_MyIter;
```

Iterator's `__iter__()` method.
It always simply returns `self`.
It allows for both iterator and collection to be treated the same
in constructs like `for ... in ...`.

```
PyObject* spam_MyIter_iter(PyObject *self)
{
  Py_INCREF(self);
  return self;
}
```

Implementation of our iteration: `next()` method.

```
PyObject* spam_MyIter_iternext(PyObject *self)
{
  spam_MyIter *p = (spam_MyIter *)self;
  if (p->i < p->m) {
    PyObject *tmp = Py_BuildValue("l", p->i);
    (p->i)++;
    return tmp;
  } else {
    /* Raising of standard StopIteration exception with empty value. */
    PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

We need extended version of `PyTypeObject` structure to provide Python with
information about `__iter__()` and `next()`.
We want them to be called efficiently, so no name-based lookup in dictionary.

```
static PyTypeObject spam_MyIterType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "spam._MyIter",            /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(spam_MyIter),       /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                         /*tp_print*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_compare*/
    0,                         /*tp_repr*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                         /*tp_hash */
    0,                         /*tp_call*/
    0,                         /*tp_str*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER,
      /* tp_flags: Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER tells python to
         use tp_iter and tp_iternext fields. */
    "Internal myiter iterator object.",           /* tp_doc */
    0,  /* tp_traverse */
    0,  /* tp_clear */
    0,  /* tp_richcompare */
    0,  /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    spam_MyIter_iter,  /* tp_iter: __iter__() method */
    spam_MyIter_iternext  /* tp_iternext: next() method */
};
```

`myiter(int)` function creates iterator.

```
static PyObject *
spam_myiter(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  long int m;
  spam_MyIter *p;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "l", &m))  return NULL;

  /* I don't need python callable __init__() method for this iterator,
     so I'll simply allocate it as PyObject and initialize it by hand. */

  p = PyObject_New(spam_MyIter, &spam_MyIterType);
  if (!p) return NULL;

  /* I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary. */
  if (!PyObject_Init((PyObject *)p, &spam_MyIterType)) {
    Py_DECREF(p);
    return NULL;
  }

  p->m = m;
  p->i = 0;
  return (PyObject *)p;
}
```

The rest is pretty boring...

```
static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    {"myiter",  spam_myiter, METH_VARARGS, "Iterate from i=0 while i<m."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
  PyObject* m;

  spam_MyIterType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
  if (PyType_Ready(&spam_MyIterType) < 0)  return;

  m = Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);

  Py_INCREF(&spam_MyIterType);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "_MyIter", (PyObject *)&spam_MyIterType);
}
```

Comment: Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER is no longer defined in python 3 as referenced by https://py3c.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-porting.html

Answer (score 5):

In `Sequence_data`, you must either return a new PyInt instance or throw a `StopIteration` exception which tells the code outside that there are no more values. See [PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) for details and [9.10 Generators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

See [Iterator Protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/iter.html) for helper functions in the Python/C API.

Comment: This describes how to create a next() method, but not how to create and return a generator object containing the method.

Comment: It's very hard to simulate "yield" in C; make the `Sequence` class an iterator instead.