# How to raise StopIteration from swig C++ code?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm trying to extend a C++ library by implementing the python iteration protocol on a class. The problem is that trying to raise a StopIteration exception from the next() method makes the program SegFault. The method I've used for raising the exception from the C++ code (in python.i) is the one described here: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn44

Although that list doesn't have the StopIteration exception listed this is what I've tried:

```
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_StopIteration, NULL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the right answer seems to be that the next() method must return a PyObject* and also use SetNone. So it would look like this:

```
PyObject* next(PyObject* self) {
  if (i < n) {
         \\ go on iterating
  } else {
         PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
         return NULL;
  }
}
```

Thanks to aix for the link!

Answer (score 1):

The segfault is almost certainly caused by the NULL pointer you've passing to `PyErr_SetString`. Try the following instead:

```
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_StopIteration, "end of collection");
```

**edit** I've just come across the following excellent post, which you may find useful: [How to create a generator/iterator with the Python C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815812/how-to-create-a-generator-iterator-with-the-python-c-api/1816961#1816961)

Comment: Yes. That doesn't seem to be recognized by the python interpreter as a StopIteration exception. It doesn't quit the loop and it just goes on forever. I think this might not be the right mechanism for raising errors at all? The code just seems to send that message to stderr, but no python exception is raised...

Comment: @mapleoin: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815812/how-to-create-a-generator-iterator-with-the-python-c-api/1816961#1816961 if you haven't already.