# Make C++ array of objects iterable in Python

Tags: c++, python, arrays, object, swig

I have searched on the web and didn't get success. I'm wrapping the sample code below to Python (using SWIG):

```
class atomo {
public:
    int i;
    atomo(int a) {
        i = a;
    };      
};

class funa {
public:
    atomo *lista[3];

    funa() {
        lista[0] = new atomo(1);
        lista[1] = new atomo(2);
        lista[2] = new atomo(3);
    };
};
```

But Python can't iterate over or access `lista` using the comands

```
>>> test = myModule.funa()
>>> test.lista[0]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 6, in __iter__
      TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not subscriptable

>>> for i in test.lista:
>>>     print(i)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 6, in __iter__
      TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I make `lista` iterable? There is a way to use Python lists instead of C++ arrays?

My Python version is 3.2 and I'm using SWIG 2.0.4 with g++ 4.6.1

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: `list(test.lista)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your question if you want to use `std::vector` or an array of your own types.

For `std::vector`, given some C++ like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct foo {
  std::string name;
};

inline std::vector<foo> test() {
  std::vector<foo> ret;
  foo instance;
  instance.name = "one";
  ret.push_back(instance);
  instance.name = "two";
  ret.push_back(instance);
  return ret;
}
```

You can wrap it with `%template`, `pyabc.i` and `std_vector.i` e.g.:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "pyabc.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

%include "test.h"

%template (FooVector) std::vector<foo>;
```

which will behave intuitively on the Python type. You'll need to call SWIG with something like:

```
swig -python -c++ -py3 -extranative test.i
```

If the idea is to wrap a "custom" container to behave intuitively on the Python side I gave a [detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776328/swig-interfacing-c-library-to-python-creating-iterable-python-data-type-from/8828454#8828454) in a previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to solve this on the Python side instead of the C++/SWIG side for simplicity.

```
# wrapper/facade
class Funa:
    def __init__(self):
        self._impl = myModule.funa()   # _impl => implementation

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(3):
            yield self._impl.lista[i]

test = Funa()
for x in test:
    print(x)
```

Comment: @user1154091: As long as you keep the inner loops in Python, you won't gain too much speed.  Move the inner loops to the C++ code to really make a difference.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: This is just a simple piece of code that shows the same error. The bottleneck of my real code is the instanciation of the class `atomo`

Comment: @CaioS.: My comment above was in response to your (now deleted) comment that you don't like this answer since it might be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896966/79513) is to have `Funa.__iter__` return a generator object.  Then you would only need to add to the interface SWIG creates.  (With his wrapping, you would have to wrap every other method, or play with `__getattr__`.)  Roughly it would be like this

```
class Funa:

  class FunaIter :
    def __init__(self, parent) :
      self.parent = parent
      self.pos = 0

    def __iter__(self) :
      while self.pos < 3 :
        yield self.parent.lista[self.pos]
        self.pos += 1

  def __iter__(self) :
    return self.FunaIter(self)
```

This should be simpler to insert into your SWIG file using the `%extend` and `%pythoncode` directives.

Also, [SWIG has wrappers for STL containers](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library), so perhaps using those, you can easily obtain the necessary item getters.