# Expose a vector as a memoryview using SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a header file like:

```
#include <vector>

inline std::vector<uint8_t>& vec() {
  static std::vector<uint8_t> v { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
  return v;
}

inline const std::vector<uint8_t>& cvec() {
  return vec();
}
```

I can [wrap it in SWIG using std_vector.i and pyabc.i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896828/make-c-array-of-objects-iterable-in-python/8898129#8898129) but that is quite inefficient (there's a jump between C++ and Python code for every access) and given that these are literally just a bunch of bytes I ought to be able to wrap them with [Python's `memoryview` interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview).

How can I expose my `std::vector<uint8_t>` as a Python `memoryview`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exposing it as a `memoryview` requires creating a `Py_buffer` first. In Python 3.3+ there is a convenient helper function, [`PyMemoryView_FromMemory`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html#PyMemoryView_FromMemory) that does a lot of the work for us. In earlier versions though we'll need to take a few extra steps, so our basic out typemap looks like:

```c
%typemap(out) std::vector<uint8_t>&, const std::vector<uint8_t>& {
  Py_buffer *buf=(Py_buffer*)malloc(sizeof *buf);
  const bool ro = info<$1_type>::is_readonly();
  if (PyBuffer_FillInfo(buf, NULL,  &((*$1)[0]), (*$1).size(), ro, PyBUF_ND)) {
    // error, handle
  }
  $result = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(buf);
}
```

Here we're basically allocating some memory for the `Py_buffer`. This just contains the details of the buffer internally for Python. The memory we allocate will be owned by the `memoryview` object once it's created. Unfortunately since it's going to be released with a call to `free()` we need to allocate it with `malloc()`, even though it's C++ code.

Besides the `Py_buffer` and an optional `Py_Object` [`PyBuffer_FillInfo`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#PyBuffer_FillInfo) takes a `void*` (the buffer itself), the size of the buffer, a boolean indicating if it's writeable and a flag. In this case our flag simply indicates that we have provided C-style contiguous memory for the buffer.

For deciding if it is readonly or not we used SWIG's built in [`$n_type`](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_special_variables) variable and a helper (which could be a C++11 type trait if we wanted).

To complete our SWIG interface we need to provide that helper and include the header file, so the whole thing becomes:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh" 

namespace {
  template <typename T>
  struct info {
    static bool is_readonly() {
      return false;
    }
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct info<const T&> {
    static bool is_readonly() {
      return true;
    }
  };
}
%}

%typemap(out) std::vector<uint8_t>&, const std::vector<uint8_t>& {
  Py_buffer *buf=(Py_buffer*)malloc(sizeof *buf);
  const bool ro = info<$1_type>::is_readonly();
  if (PyBuffer_FillInfo(buf, NULL,  &((*$1)[0]), (*$1).size(), ro, PyBUF_ND)) {
    // error, handle
  }
  $result = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(buf);
}

%include "test.hh"
```

We can then test it with:

```
import test

print test.vec()
print len(test.vec())
print test.vec()[0]
print test.vec().readonly
test.vec()[0]='z'
print test.vec()[0]

print "This should fail:"
test.cvec()[0] = 0
```

Which worked as expected, tested using Python 2.7.

Compared to just wrapping it using std_vector.i this approach does have some drawbacks. The biggest being that we can't resize the vector, or convert it back to a vector later trivially. We could work around that, at least partially by creating a SWIG proxy for the vector like normal and using the second parameter of `PyBuffer_FillInfo` to store it internally. (This would also be needed if we had to manage the ownership of the vector for instance).