# Fill char* with binary data in a c++ Python wrapped class with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig, binary-data

I have wrapped a c++ class with swig for python use. My class is something like:

```
public class DataHolder
{
public:
     char* BinaryData;
     long Length;
}

public class MyProcessor
{
public:
    int process(DataHolder& holder)
    {
          holder.BinaryData = assign some binary data;
          holder.Length = 1024;
    }
}
```

What i want from python is something like this:

```
import Module
from Module import *

proc = MyProcessor();
holder = DataHolder();

proc.process(holder);

#use holder.BinaryData to, for example, print
```

Any help will be very appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998686/expose-a-vector-as-a-memoryview-using-swig solve it for you?

Comment: Thank you @Flexo,
This example that you mentioned is using a vector, i was wondering if it would work for a char* too? 
Currently, the best way I have found to handle this is through cdata.i and converting my char* to void* in my c++ code but I am still looking for a way to not change my c++ to void*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example C++ code isn't quite legal (it looks more like Java!), but once I fixed that and added something real for `process` to do I was able to wrap it as you hoped.

Compared to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998686/expose-a-vector-as-a-memoryview-using-swig) the main change is that the length gets read from inside the class, rather than being the result of calling a method on a container. This is kind of ugly, because I had to hardcode the name of the C++ 'this' object, `$self` referred to the Python object. Due to that I made the typemap only get applied in restricted circumstances where we're sure it's legal and correct.

So my final interface file ended up looking like:

```
%module test

%typemap(out) char *DataHolder::BinaryData {
  Py_buffer *buf=(Py_buffer*)malloc(sizeof *buf);
  if (PyBuffer_FillInfo(buf, NULL, $1, arg1->Length, true, PyBUF_ND)) {
    // Error, handle
  }
  $result = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(buf);
}

%inline %{
class DataHolder
{
public:
     char* BinaryData;
     long Length;
};

class MyProcessor
{
public:
    int process(DataHolder& holder)
    {
          static char val[] = "Hello\0Binary\0World\n!";
          holder.BinaryData = val;
          holder.Length = sizeof val;
          return 0;
    }
};
%}
```

Which I tested with:

```
from test import *
proc = MyProcessor()
holder = DataHolder()

proc.process(holder)

data = holder.BinaryData
print(repr(data))
print(data.tobytes())
```

I targeted Python3 here, but the exact same code should work for Python 2.7. When compiled and run this gave:

```
swig2.0 -c++ -Wall -py3 -python test.i
g++ -Wall  -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.4
python3 run.py
<memory at 0xb7271f9c>
b'Hello\x00Binary\x00World\n!\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! This is great! Many questions answered by this one post!
Many Many Many thanks!