# How to add python wrap to already swig wrapped C++ class

Tags: python, c++, swig, word-wrap

I have a simple user defined StringList class in `C++`. Its underlying container is a std::vector.

It would be convenient, when using this class in python, to have any `StringList` object converted to a Python list whenever returned by a python wrapped object.

The StringList class do contain a function, `getContainer()`, that do return a reference to the underlying `vector<string>` object, and I would think this function could be used somehow?

For example, the C++ code

```
Raven aRaven;
StringList molecules;
molecules = aRaven.getMoleculesInDB();
```

populates the molecules object with a list of moleculenames (strings).

In Python, this looks like this, including code to loop over the list:

```
aRaven = Raven()
molecules = aRaven.getMoleculesInDB()

print 'There are ' + `molecules.count()` +' available.' 
for mol in range(molecules.count()):
    molName = molecules.at(mol)                
...
```

It is desirable to instead of creating a StringList object in the aRaven.getMoleculesInDb(), creating a Python list with strings (from the underlying std::vector container). Then the user could write

```
aRaven = Raven()
molecules = aRaven.getMoleculesInDB() # <--- Returns a Python list of strings

for molName in molecules:
    print 'molName'
...
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this in the swig interface file?

Comment: Do you mean have it converted to a Python list?  I'm not 100% clear on which part of the Python-C++ interaction you're trying to improve--Python calling C++ or the other way.

Comment: Post the python code you would like to be able to write, this will clarify a few things.

Comment: I updated the question with some code showing what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a python list to get that behaviour, implementing the iterator protocol is enough. Does my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776328/swig-interfacing-c-library-to-python-creating-iterable-python-data-type-from/8828454#8828454 cover it for you?