# swig: How to make a QList<T> iterable, like std::vector

Tags: python, c++, qt, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate Python Bindings for my qt app. I have several places where I use [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html)s and I would like to integrate those QLists like std::vector from the SWIG Library (see http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn15).
This means:

- The QList objects should be iterable from python (= they must be an iterable python object)
- It should be possible to pass a python list to a function which takes a qlist
- ... and all the other features listed in the SWIG Library for std::vector

To achieve that I use the following Code:
https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-core/blob/master/swig/java/QList.i
Later in my classes using QLists, I add code like:

```
%import "qlist.i"
%template(listfilter) QList<Interface_Filter*>;

class A {
    public:
    //.....
    QList<Interface_Filter*> get_filters();
};
```

This works so far, but it doesn't give me the kind of integration I get with std::vector.
I'm having trouble finding out which parts of std_vector.i, std_container.i,... make an object iterable.
**How do I need to extend the QList interface file to make my QList's iterable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for -- a qlist.i swig file that achieves the same level of integration for `QList` in python as std_vector.i does for `std::vector` -- is a non-trivial task.

I provide a very basic extended qlist.i file (and qlisttest.i to show you how to use it) and will try to explain what steps are required.

`qlist.i`:

```
%{
#include <QList>
%}

%pythoncode %{
class QListIterator:
    def __init__(self, qlist):
        self.index = 0
        self.qlist = qlist
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.index >= self.qlist.size():
            raise StopIteration;
        ret = self.qlist.get(self.index)
        self.index += 1
        return ret
    __next__ = next
%}

template<class T> class QList {
public:
class iterator;
typedef size_t size_type;
typedef T value_type;
typedef const value_type& const_reference;
QList();
size_type size() const;
void reserve(size_type n);
%rename(isEmpty) empty;
bool empty() const;
void clear();
%rename(add) push_back;
void push_back(const value_type& x);
%extend {
    const_reference get(int i) throw (std::out_of_range) {
    int size = int(self->size());
    if (i>=0 && i<size)
        return (*self)[i];
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("QList index out of range");
    }
    void set(int i, const value_type& val) throw (std::out_of_range) {
    int size = int(self->size());
    if (i>=0 && i<size)
        (*self)[i] = val;
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("QList index out of range");
    }
    int __len__() {
    return self->size();
    }
    const_reference __getitem__(int i) throw (std::out_of_range) {
    int size = int(self->size());
    if (i>=0 && i<size)
        return (*self)[i];
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("QList index out of range");
    }
    %pythoncode %{
    def __iter__(self):
        return QListIterator(self)
    %}
}
};

%define %qlist_conversions(Type...)
%typemap(in) const QList< Type > & (bool free_qlist)
{
free_qlist = false;
if ((SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &$1, $1_descriptor, 0)) == -1) {
    if (!PyList_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "QList or python list required.");
    SWIG_fail;
    }
    Py_ssize_t len = PyList_Size($input);
    QList< Type > * qlist = new QList< Type >();
    free_qlist = true;
    qlist->reserve(len);
    for (Py_ssize_t index = 0; index < len; ++index) {
    PyObject *item = PyList_GetItem($input,index);
    Type* c_item;
    if ((SWIG_ConvertPtr(item, (void **) &c_item, $descriptor(Type *),0)) == -1) {
        delete qlist;
        free_qlist = false;
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "List element of wrong type encountered.");
        SWIG_fail;
    }
    qlist->append(*c_item);
    }
    $1 = qlist;
}
}
%typemap(freearg) const QList< Type > &
{ if (free_qlist$argnum and $1) delete $1; }    
%enddef
```

`qlisttest.i`:

```
%module qlist;
%include "qlist.i"

%inline %{
class Foo {
public:
    int foo;
};
%}

%template(QList_Foo) QList<Foo>;
%qlist_conversions(Foo);

%inline %{  
int sumList(const QList<Foo> & list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        sum += list[i].foo;
    }
    return sum;
}
%}
```

1. Wrapping of `QList` to make it and its methods accessible from python
   This is achieved by making the (partial) class definition available to swig. That is what your current `qlist.i` does.
   **Note:** You might need to add a "template specialization" for the case `QList<T*>` that typedefs `const_reference` as `const T*` since you are using a `QList` of pointers. Otherwise, `QList<T*>::const_reference` will be `const T*&`, which apparently might confuse swig. (see [swig/Lib/std/std_vector.i](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/std/std_vector.i#L97-100))
2. Automatic conversion between python list and `QList`
   This is generally achieved by using swig [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps). For instance, if you want a function `f(const QList<int>& list)` to be able to accept a python list, you need to specify an input typemap that performs the conversion from a python list to a `QList<int>`:

   ```
   %typemap(in) const QList<int> &
   {
       PyObject * py_list = $input;
       [check if py_list is really a python list of integers]
       QList<int>* qlist = new QList<int>();
       [copy the data from the py_list to the qlist]
       $1 = qlist;
   }
   %typemap(freearg) const QList<int> &
   { if ($1) delete $1; }
   ```

   Here, the situation is more difficult in several ways:

   - You want to be able to pass a python lists *or* a wrapped `QList`: For this to work, you need to handle both cases in the typemap.
   - You want to convert a python list of wrapped type `T` to a `QList<T>`:
     This also involves a conversion for every element of the list from the wrapped type `T` to the plain `T`. This is achieved by the swig function `SWIG_ConvertPtr`.
   - I am not sure if you can specify typemaps with template arguments. Therefore, I wrote a swig macro `%qlist_conversions(Type)` that you can use to attach the typemap to the `QList<Type>` for a specific `Type`.

   For the other conversion direction (`QList` -> python list) you should first consider what you want. Consider a C++ function that returns a `QList<int>`. Calling this from python, should this return a wrapped `QList` object, or should it automatically convert the `QList` to a python list?
3. Accessing the wrapped `QList` as a python sequence, i.e., make `len` and `[]` work from python
   For this, you need to extend the `QList` class in the qlist.i file using `%extend { ... }` and implement `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods.

   If slicing should also work, you need to provide a `__getitem__(PySliceObject *slice)__` member method and input and "typecheck" typemaps for `PySliceObject`s.

   If you want to be able to modify values in the wrapped `QList` using `[]` from python, you need to implement `__setitem__`.

   For a list of all the useful methods you can implement to achieve better integration, see the python documentation on "builtin types" and "abstract base classes for containers".

   **Note:** If you use the swig `-builtin` feature, then you need to additionally register the above functions to the appropriate "slots" using e.g.

   ```
   %feature("python:slot", "sq_length", functype="lenfunc") __len__;
   ```
4. Making the wrapped `QList` iterable from python
   For this you need to extend the `QList` class and implement an `__iter__()` method that returns a python iterator object.

   A python iterator object is an object that provides the methods `__iter__()` and `__next__()` (`next()` for older python), where `__next__()` returns the next value and raises the python exception `StopIteration` to signal the end.

   As mentioned before, you can implement the iterator object in python or C++. I show an example of doing this in python.

I hope this helps as a basis for you to tweak the functionality that you require.

Comment: Thank you sir, for providing (almost completely) what I asked for. I'll try out the code tomorrow, and come back with questions/comments.
I was not aware that this would be that complicated. What puzzles me most, is that std_vector.i can be used with one simple line: `%template(vectori) vector<int>;`. How do they do that?!  Are we missing something here?

Comment: SWIG contains a library of functions that do what I did above in a generic and much more sophisticated way. See e.g. [typemaps](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Lib/typemaps) and [std](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Lib/std) for the language independent code, and [pycontainer.swg](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pycontainer.swg) and [pyiterators.swg](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pyiterators.swg) for the relevant python code.

Comment: However, that is difficult to use. First of all, they recommend for the implementation files: "don't look at them unless you are really drunk", which really says it all... Secondly, they are STL specific, and QList is not fully STL compatible (e.g., lacking `reverse_iterator`)

Comment: Ah, I was only looking in the language independent code and never came across `pycontainer.swg` and `pyiterators.swg` files.
I can still combine your 2 lines from `qlisttest.i` in a define, and then I have also a "*one single line, which does it all*"-kind of integration.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), you need the following:

- QList should have a method in python `__iter__()` that returns an iterator object (`tp_iter` if you implement it in C).
- The iterator object should implement `__iter__()` and return itself
- The iterator object should implement `next()` that returns the next item or raises `StopIteration` when it's done.

It's probably easiest to do in python, but you can implement it in C as well.

Another option is to use python generators to avoid implementing an iterator type. To do this you QList needs to implement `__iter__()` but instead of returning an iterator you simply `yield` the values.

The methods mentioned only need to be visible to python. You don't have to make them available in C/Java.

See also [SWIG interfacing C library to Python (Creating 'iterable' Python data type from C 'sequence' struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776328/swig-interfacing-c-library-to-python-creating-iterable-python-data-type-from)

Comment: You provided an answer to the question "How to make a python Object iterable", but I asked for  "**How do I need to extend the QList interface file to make my QList's iterable?**" which is more a SWIG, than a python related question.

Comment: @Dreamcooled I thought you knew that. See docs: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn43 -  31.6.3 Class extension with %extend .

Comment: I did know about `%extend`, but it's not done with that. As stated in the Bounty Text, **I would like to see a complete interface file for qlist.i**, which behaves like std_vector.i but operates on QLists.

Answer (score 0):

> You provided an answer to the question "How to make a python Object iterable", but I asked for "How do I need to extend the QList interface file to make my QList's iterable?" which is more a SWIG, than a python related question.

I tested the example from http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn15 with Java, C# and Python. Only Python and C# provide iterators. The generated interface of Java doesn't implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) or something like that. As far as I can see your question is related to the target language.

Maybe extending [MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) is an option for you. The only methods you have to implement are `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__len__` and `insert` by delegating them to the corresponding methods of QList. Afterwards your generated class is iterable.

Comment: As I stated in the Question, I was unable to find the parts which make a std_vector iterable in python, inside the std_vector.i file from the Swig Library. Your's and also Sorin's answer are both very generic and are not really SWIG related. As stated in the Bounty Text, **I would like to see a complete interface file for qlist.i**, which behaves like std_vector.i but operates on [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html)s.