# SWIG Mapping C++ array to Python sequence

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have some C++ code wrapped using SWIG, and want to map a simple array of objects to a Python list. A much simplified example:

```
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;
};

class Polygon {
  Point *ptlist();
  int numPoints();
...
};
```

I want to be able to access ptlist() in Python as a sequence of Points, but can't find any obvious way of doing this using e.g. %extend or typemaps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote an answer that outlines a few approaches to this problem a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8828454/168175 does that solve it for you?

Comment: Thanks, the typemap example helped solve the problem.

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate then on that basis, but I'm more than happy to reopen this if you don't agree.