# Using swig to convert C link to Python list

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a C written library and I use swig to get a python wrapper. All types are defined in test.h and function implemented in test.c. I used swig to define a test.i like:

```
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

Everything ran smoothly. However, I have some structure defined in .h like

```
typedef struct sth STH;
struct sth {
char *name;
STH *next;
}
```

So right now, the names in python has to be used as .name .next.name and go on like that. Is there any way I can change the C style link to a list in python?

Where is the best step I change them? in the .i file or I have to change test_wrapper.c file?
Thanks

Comment: I think my 3rd example at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8828454/168175 should cover this.